# docker + node.js + pm2 : can't run docker in daemon mode?

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I build docker image of node.js app and run.
but pm2 was run no daemon mode and stream all logs of pm2
I want run node.js in production environment.
when I exit container, process was killed and pm2 was stopped
how can i run node js app in docker container like background mode or daemon mode

it is my Dockerfile

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:12-stretch
MAINTAINER steve.lim@havehad.kr

# 소스 복사
COPY . /usr/src/app
# wokrdir 설정
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install
RUN npm install

# 서버 실행
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.json", "--env", "production" ]
```

it is my pm2.json

```
{
  "name": "havehad-v3-backend",
  "script": "./bin/www",
  "exec_mode" : "fork",
  "interpreter": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
  "interpreter_args": "--presets @babel/preset-env",
  "out_file" : "/usr/src/app/.pmw/log",
  "error_file": "/usr/src/app/.pmw/log",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3001,
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "env_test": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "NODE_ENV": "test"
  },
  "env_production" : {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "NODE_ENV": "production"
  }
}
```

please help me

Thank you

Comment: did you run it detached? `-d`?

Comment: oh! thank you. problem is solved.  
i think pm2 should run foreground mode. so i didn't try '-d'